# Is the v1.02 patch still available for the Dos game Alien Logic?

Tags: alien-logic

Here's the game in question: [Alien Logic](http://www.mobygames.com/game/alien-logic) (@ Moby Games)

My question is this:
Does anybody know if the patch is still available, and if so, where it can be found? I am looking for the 1.02 patch, which I assume is the latest (and last) official version of the game.

I am working off of the original disc and not a downloaded and compiled zip (as available on some abandonware sites). The version on the disc installs as v1.00

The FAQ on Gamefaqs suggests to get if from the [Broderbund support page](http://support.broderbund.com/) but the page doesn't seem to be there anymore. The posting date of the FAQ in question is 2007, so it is a *bit* outdated.

Here is the [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/564988-skyrealms-of-jorune-alien-logic/faqs/48902) at Gamefaqs, if this concerns anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the Patch is available here, it's the one called Alien102.zip http://www.gamers.org/pub/archives/uwp-uml/patches/

It seems some people may be wary of downloading the zip file, there are only two things I can say to that, 1st the .txt by the same name there indicates clearly that this is for the right game, it also details the fix etc. I've downloaded the .ZIP myself, and confirm that it is the right file.

I know you now have nothing more than my word on the fact that it's the right file, but, well, it is and this seems to be the only place you can readily get a copy of it too, all other locations are no longer in existence.

I've been a big fan of this game for almost 20 years, so would hate to see the final patch disappear, and giving this answer was actually my sole reason for signing up to this site. I'll be keeping this copy of said file very safe from now on, given that it's now so difficult to find and who knows when it may be gone for good...

My best to any fellow AL fans.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting down voted? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I'm only just seeing this, but I'd hazard a guess that it's because there's no real indication on the site that it's actually for Alien Logic. I'm not going to down vote,  but I wouldn't want to download an unknown file either.

Comment: I'll update the answer in a second as well, however I have downloaded the ZIP, and within that is a .txt which clearly identifies it as the right file, details what was fixed etc. Hope that helps, other than this location this patch may be lost to us... :(

Comment: And it was a random discussion with colleagues about classic gaming that lead me to your 3 year old question, followed by a frantic search of the web, was a bit like a treasure hunt... actually had some fun tracking it down.

Comment: Coming back to this question later, I'd like to say I still have my copy safe and sound! I've also accepted the answer, something I should have done 2 years ago. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

It also seems that the patch is known by the version 1.1 and may be found [here](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/959-alien-logic-a-skyrealms-of-jorune-adventure-patch/) (PC Gaming Wiki), though the change-log is exactly the same.